# Do fire spells cast underwater still affect creatures vulnerable to fire?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, spells

**Related Question:** [Can magic items that deal fire damage function underwater?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6190/can-magic-items-that-deal-fire-damage-function-underwater)

As mentioned in the above question:

From the DMG p93:

> Spells or spell-like effects with the
>   fire descriptor are ineffective
>   underwater unless the caster makes a
>   Spellcraft check (DC 20 + spell
>   level). If the check succeeds, the
>   spell creates a bubble of steam
>   instead of its usual fiery effect, but
>   otherwise the spell works as
>   described. A supernatural fire effect
>   is ineffective underwater unless its
>   description states otherwise.

For creatures that have damage reduction x/fire or regenerate damage except that done by fire, do they treat the bubble of steam the same as fire or not? eg Would a Water Troll regenerate damage from a fireball cast underwater?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> If the check succeeds, the spell creates a bubble of steam instead of its usual fiery effect, but *otherwise the spell works as described*.

Sounds like fire damage to me, but you're burning them with superheated steam instead of flame.

Comment: Yes. Notably, *[heat metal](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/heatMetal.htm)* doesn't produce a naked flame yet it explicitly says that a creature takes fire damage if its equipment is heated, so as far as the rules are concerned, "really hot" == "fire".